# How do boundaries work in multipart post requests?

Tags: iphone, http, post, http-post, multipartform-data

I trying to upload a file from an iPhone to a server. I'm trying to avoid using any libraries that aren't made by apple, and from what I can tell it looks like I'll need to go pretty low level on constructing my request. Can someone tell me what the "boundary" is in a multipart/form-data request and how to use it properly?

Comment: Are you writing iPhone code, or server code?

Comment: Both, but I'm asking about constructing the request on the client side (iphone).

Answer (score 8):

The boundary is an arbitrary piece of text which the client uses to delimit the fields of the form being posted. The client declares the boundary it is using as part of the `Content-type` header.

[From the IETF  **Form-based File Upload in HTML** RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt):

> A boundary is selected that does not occur in any of the data. (This
>      selection is sometimes done probabilisticly.) Each field of the form
>      is sent, in the order in which it occurs in the form, as a part of
>      the multipart stream.  Each part identifies the INPUT name within the
>      original HTML form. Each part should be labelled with an appropriate
>      content-type if the media type is known (e.g., inferred from the file
>      extension or operating system typing information) or as
>      application/octet-stream.
>
> ...
>
> 6. Examples
>
> Suppose the server supplies the following HTML:
>
> ```
> <FORM ACTION="http://server.dom/cgi/handle"
>        ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data"
>        METHOD=POST>
>  What is your name? <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=submitter>
>  What files are you sending? <INPUT TYPE=FILE NAME=pics>
>  </FORM>
> ```
>
> and the user types "Joe Blow" in the name field, and selects a text
>   file "file1.txt" for the answer to 'What files are you sending?'
>
> The client might send back the following data:
>
> ```
>    Content-type: multipart/form-data, boundary=AaB03x
>
>    --AaB03x
>    content-disposition: form-data; name="field1"
>
>    Joe Blow
>    --AaB03x
>    content-disposition: form-data; name="pics"; filename="file1.txt"
>    Content-Type: text/plain
>
>     ... contents of file1.txt ...
>    --AaB03x--
> ```
>
> If the user also indicated an image file "file2.gif" for the answer
>   to 'What files are you sending?', the client might client might send
>   back the following data:
>
> ```
>    Content-type: multipart/form-data, boundary=AaB03x
>
>    --AaB03x
>    content-disposition: form-data; name="field1"
>
>    Joe Blow
>    --AaB03x
>    content-disposition: form-data; name="pics"
>    Content-type: multipart/mixed, boundary=BbC04y
>
>    --BbC04y
>    Content-disposition: attachment; filename="file1.txt"
> ```

In the first example, the boundary is the fixed string `AaB03x`. In the second example, the boundary is first `AaB03x` and then switches to `BbC04y`.